# How to query display data horizontally?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

This is the data I have in my table

```
id  id_mst_tag  value  time      date
1   1           100    16:18:25  2019-10-04
2   2           300    14:10:12  2019-10-04
3   1           90     18:11:22  2019-10-04
4   2           299    18:15:34  2019-10-04
5   1           98     20:13:45  2019-10-04
6   2           311    20:18:25  2019-10-04
7   3           OFF    22:13:21  2019-10-04
```

and I want to show it horizontally like this

```
id_mst_tag 14:00 16:00 18:00 20:00 22:00
1          NULL  100   90    98    NULL
2          300   NULL  299   311   NULL    
3          NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  OFF
```

How can I make like this ? please help

Answer (score 0):

You can consider GROUP BY and CASE combination as below to get your desired output.

> **Note**: You have Integer and Text value in the column "Value" which is not realistic. Hope there are NULL in place of OFF in the table. Anyway, you can apply the following logic with data in correct format in column "Value".

```
SELECT id_mst_tag,
SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(time) = 14 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) `14:00`,
SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(time) = 16 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) `16:00`,
SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(time) = 18 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) `18:00`,
SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(time) = 20 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) `20:00`,
SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(time) = 22 THEN Value ELSE 0 END) `22:00`
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id_mst_tag
```

But still, if you have that "OFF" is there in the database, you can try this following option with one additional level of data casting as below-

```
SELECT id_mst_tag,
SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(time) = 14 THEN (CASE WHEN Value = 'OFF' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(Value,UNSIGNED INTEGER) END) ELSE 0 END) `14:00`,
SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(time) = 16 THEN (CASE WHEN Value = 'OFF' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(Value,UNSIGNED INTEGER) END) ELSE 0 END) `16:00`,
SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(time) = 18 THEN (CASE WHEN Value = 'OFF' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(Value,UNSIGNED INTEGER) END) ELSE 0 END) `18:00`,
SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(time) = 20 THEN (CASE WHEN Value = 'OFF' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(Value,UNSIGNED INTEGER) END) ELSE 0 END) `20:00`,
SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(time) = 22 THEN (CASE WHEN Value = 'OFF' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(Value,UNSIGNED INTEGER) END) ELSE 0 END) `22:00`
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id_mst_tag;
```